# Why GIthub Folder Button broken?

Tags: html, django, github

I git pushed my projected to my Github page,
but a few important folder didn't seem to work and can't see the content.
And even when I download all folders in zip file, still nothings contained in it.
I mean, the start folder should contain all of my files and activated.
The original folder has full content, so I have no idea what to do.
Noghing errors thrown while I push those to Github.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The original folder has full content, so I have no idea what to do

The original folder start *also* has a `.git/` subfolder in it.
That makes start a *nested Git repository*, which will be pushed to GitHub as this "gray (empty) folder", representing a "gitlink" (a special entry in the index), which is the nested repository root tree SHA1.

You would need to:

```
git rm start     # no trailing stash
rm -Rf start/git # if you don't care about the start history
git add start
git commit -m "Add start content"
git push
```